# Add the same element of array in a existing JSON using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json file and I want to add some value from top in another place in json.
I am trying to use jq command line.

```
{
    "channel": "mychannel",
    "videos": [
        {
            "id": "10",
            "url": "youtube.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "20", 
            "url": "youtube.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The output would be:

```
{
    "channel": "mychannel",
    "videos": [
        {
            "channel": "mychannel",
            "id": "10",
            "url": "youtube.com"
        },
        {
            "channel": "mychannel",
            "id": "20", 
            "url": "youtube.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

in my json the "channel" is static, same value always. I need a way to concatenate always in each video array.

Someone can help me?

jq .videos + channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable to remember `.channel` in the later stages of the pipeline.

```
$ jq '.channel as $ch | .videos[].channel = $ch' tmp.json
{
  "channel": "mychannel",
  "videos": [
    {
      "id": "10",
      "url": "youtube.com",
      "channel": "mychannel"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "url": "youtube.com",
      "channel": "mychannel"
    }
  ]
}
```